# Not get "et al." in Harvard reference list

Tags: biblatex, harvard-style

I have changed the reference style from APA to Harvard, and now the references with more than three authors appear in the reference list as "first author et al.".
This is how I am calling biblatex at the beginning of my tex file.

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
```

How can I make all authors show up in the reference list but still get "et al." when I reference in the text?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you change

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
```

to

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear,maxbibnames=999]{biblatex}
```

I'd drop the option `backend=bibtex` unless you have a very good reason for wanting to avoid using the default back-end (`biber`).